# Что приводит к ошибке "Found shared references to a collection"?

Tags: java, hibernate

В чем причина возникновения ошибок "nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found shared references to a collection"?

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том, что `hibernate` пытается сохранить объект который ссылается на несуществующий в базе объект!

Comment: Таки нет, хибер явно пишет, что одна коллекция оказалась в нескольких сущностях.

Comment: У меня получилось иссправить ошибку, когда я начал исспользовать 2 разных коллекции для хранения одного типа сущностей в одном методе